# Getting the peer multiaddr from IPFS Swarm peers

Tags: javascript, node.js, ipfs

I'm trying to decode the buffer stored in the *addr* key found in the output returned by the IPFS [swarm peers](https://github.com/ipfs/interface-js-ipfs-core/blob/master/SPEC/SWARM.md#swarmpeers) function back to the original string. I tried to use the [toString()](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_buf_tostring_encoding_start_end) method with all supported encodings, but the output I'm getting is not correctly decoded.

```
const swarm_peers = await node.swarm.peers(); 
console.log(swarm_peers['2']['addr']['buffer'].toString());
```

Below is a sample output of what I'm getting

6sgp-1.bootstrap.libp2p.io���" BD�38\

How do I correctly decode the buffer?

Comment: Can you share the snippet of code where you are trying to do so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should  not call `toString()` on raw `buffer`, but on `addr` object:

```js
const peers = await node.swarm.peers()
peers.forEach(peer => console.log(peer.addr.toString()))
```